# RedirectToAction Bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, beta

I Have following code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Step1()
{
        return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Step1(FormCollection form)
{
        TempData["messageStatus"] = new Random().Next(1, 1000);
        return RedirectToAction("Step1");
}
```

View:

```
<%=TempData["messageStatus"]%>
```

in first time in view im getting **12345** for example, but when i request second time of course i must get something else instead **12345** for example **54321** but not, im getting same result **12345**, how can u explain it? **RedirectToAction** cache pages?

where does it mean i must put Guid in my urls for resolving problems with cache? what do u think about this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running into caching problems. It's not a problem with redirect to action. All RedirectToAction does is issues a redirect response to your browser telling it to request Step01. Then your browser makes a request for Step01.

In that case, your browser might have Step01 cached. So you need to add a Response header in STep01 indicating it should never be cached. You can do this like so:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public ActionResult Step1()
{
        return View();
}
```

Or you can add a random querystring to the redirect to action call by passing in an arbitrary value.

Comment: thanks i will use outputcache in my base controller instead random

Answer (score 1):

Don't new up a new Random object every time. Use the same one. Remember, the .Net Random is only a Pseudo random number generator.

Comment: i used random for example only, i prefer guid :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TempData["messageStatus"] = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Next(1, 1000);
```

Comment: There's no overload for Random that takes a DateTime. It takes an int, so you can use DateTime.Now.Millisecond.

Comment: but i dont want improve random method, i just want know that its ok that  redirect cache pages